# Error uploading Arduino Mirco Sketch using Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arduino, arduino-ide

I have an arduino micro which I want to program from my Kubuntu 15.10 system. I installed the arduino software using apt-get, but when I try to upload the program (for test purpose I use the Basics\BareMinimum sketch) I get the following error:

```
Found programmer: Id = "0.00 V1"; type =  
    Software Version = 0..; Hardware Version = 0.0
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
```

The proper device "Arduino Micro" is selected and also the proper port "/tty/ACM0". I found people on the internet which have the same error and could solve it by using another USB port or cable. But I tried it with two different cables and different ports and didn't manage to get it working. I even tried it on my Laptop running an older version of Kubuntu which produced the same error.

Therefore I tried the newest version of the Arduino software from the arduino homepage. With this I get a different error:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Device or resource busy
avrdude: ser_send(): write error: Bad file descriptor
```

My user is added to the dialout group, so I should have access to the port. It is also the right port as the port disappears from the arduino menu when I unplug the board.

The arduino itself shouldn't be the problem, as I can upload the sketch from another windows laptop without problems.

EDIT: when I plug in the arduino, the following is added to the `dmesg` output:

```
[ 8390.293960] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 8390.424861] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=8037
[ 8390.424863] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 8390.424864] usb 1-2: Product: Arduino Micro
[ 8390.424865] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Arduino LLC
[ 8390.425283] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 8390.426815] input: Arduino LLC Arduino Micro as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:2341:8037.0007/input/input21
[ 8390.482163] hid-generic 0003:2341:8037.0007: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [Arduino LLC Arduino Micro] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you flash Arduino bootloader? You can recognize it by glowing LED when you power your board. It glows for few seconds and then it starts currently flashed sketch.

If you don't see glowing LED, you need to flash the bootloader first.

In `avrdude` you should use `AVR109` bootloader - that is correct.

You can observe `dmesg` command output to see how your board is detected.

Comment: I can program the arduino from a windows pc, so I think the bootloader on the Arduino should be there.

Comment: Error says "device or resource busy". Use `lsof` to see what process hangs on `/dev/ttyACM0`. I believe that Ubuntu has (or had in the past) some modem daemon that attaches like a leech to anything that looks like a serial line. Slurp...

Comment: So I should just call `lsof /dev/ttyACM0`? this doesn't give any output, just does nothing, without and with the arduino software running.

Comment: Yes, I have. It makes not difference. When the arduino is connected, I get an empty output, if it is disconnected, I get an `status error on /dev/ttyACM0: No such file or directory` error.

Comment: Can you paste `dmesg` output after connecting the device?

Comment: As the comments don't support good output formatting, I added the output to the question post.

Comment: Interesting, it has some HID function. I'm wondering if something is attaching to HID interface, causing CDC to malfunction (aka "firmware bug"). X Window may do some automagic here. Try flashing blinking LED on Windows and try again, ensuring that it's not detected as composite device (many USB functions in one). That should confirm or debunk my theory.

Comment: I am not sure what you want me to do. I uploaded the Basics\Blink sketch on the Arduino using Windows10 and plugged it in to the Kubuntu PC and received the same `dmesg` output as before.